# Android - Getting database ID from ListView selection

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-listview, cursor

I have a `ListView lv` which uses a `Cursor c` from an SQL database to populate it. When an item is selected however, I need to get the ID of the row. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using a SimpleCursorAdapter (or similar), so I would use the [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // id references the SQLiteDatabase _id column
    }
});
```

Comment: But how do I get the ID of the selected item?

Comment: When the user clicks on a ListView row it calls `onItemSelected()`. Inside `onItemSelected()` there is the variable `id`, this is the id from the ID column.

Comment: [`View.getId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getId%28%29) returns the R file's unique id to your View (for example `R.id.listview` is really a reference to a number). This id is not the same as a SQLite `_id`...

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it worked out for me. In an other class, I have created a method of List type and added the column id & the name of the item in the list from the sqlite database.

Here's the piece of code to retrieve the column id of the selected item.

```
    public List<String> list;
    adapt = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_inner_view, list); //custom adapter
    listTask.setAdapter(adapt);

    listTask.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int position, long l) {

           Integer id = list.get(position).getId();
          //position is the position of the item in the list.
       }
   });
```

Result: the item is at 3rd position in the list. Its database column_id (auto increment) value is 12 because I have deleted previous items. So the result you expect is 12, which is the value of variable id.

If you don't understand this fully, it may be because I haven't posted my entire code. But I'll help you out with your problem.